# WordPress - Enter password in a password-protected page but page keeps redirecting back to enter password

Tags: wordpress

I've implemented a password-protected page on WordPress, but every time I put in the correct password, I get **redirected back** to the same page to enter the password again.

Here is my code to implement a password-protected page on WordPress:

```
<?php if ( !post_password_required() ) { ?>

  // put content here

<?php } else { ?>

<?php echo get_the_password_form(); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I've implemented this same code for other websites and it has worked fine in the past, but I'm unsure why this one is not working.

Would anyone have experience as to what is going on? Maybe there's a cache issue?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Too many unknowns.  Are you sure the password entered is correct? Where specifically does this code live on your page?

Comment: I'm very sure that I have the password entered correctly because I literally copied and pasted it into the field, pressed the Enter button, and then promptly redirected back to the same page to enter the password. This code lives on a template page called "Form Page" and the page I'm using is using this template to display a form only meant for internal uses only. Any other unknowns let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Your global `$post` probably isn't set up wherever you're showing this code. According to the docs, [`post_password_required()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_password_required/) takes an optional `WP_Post` object or `$post_id` as an argument.

Try `if ( ! post_password_required( get_the_ID() ) ) {`

Otherwise it means the "correct password cookie" isn't being set - make sure that you have cookies enabled.